# Develop ios app using phonegap without mac

Tags: ios, macos, jquery-mobile, cordova

Do I have to use apple mac in order to develop a hybrid app using phonegap and jquerymobile?

I intend using phonegap build, and I would like to test and publish the app in the appstore.

Can I create the key for the phonegap ios app using windows, instead of mac?

Comment: you need mac to test on apple device..

Comment: I have ipad to test on a device. but do I need a mac? I developed using phonegap to wrap my css/js/html5 files?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need apple mac. Phonegap creates individual projects for each operating system you make your app for.

Xcode project is made for the iOS one and to open that as well as to archive and create ipa file , you need MAC OS.

There are other ways to run MAC OS in windows but they are not legal and also can have bugs which you wont get support on.

Comment: according to this link you do not have to have a mac to do so: http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/11/phonegap/building-an-ios-signing-key-for-phonegap-in-windows

Comment: you might be able to build iOS .p12 and .pem files for ipa generation but submission to app store still requires MAC/xcode  https://discussions.apple.com/message/21453688#21453688

Answer (score 2):

NO, you DON'T NEED A MAC to develop a hybrid app. I found this cool cloud based IDE called [Monaca](http://monaca.mobi/en/). It has PhoneGap inside its framework. In other words, you can create PhoneGap apps with it by using HTML5 and Javascript. What impressive about it is how you can debug your app on your device during the development without the need of building it each and every time. I hope this help you to develop your hybrid app easier.

Cheer.

Comment: You are right, you don't need it to develop, but you need it for app submission to the app store

Comment: Yes, you are right. As I mentioned above it's okay to develop without a Mac but when you publish you will need one.