# Deploying app for personal use on iOS device

Tags: ios, deployment, flutter, progressive-web-apps

I want to build a very simple gallery like app (which uses the Telegram bot API to fetch images from certain telegram channel). I want to have this app for both Android and iOS device. I guess either progressive web app or flutter could be used to achieve this. I have developed native android apps before, and wish to learn PWA or flutter along with this project.

So my question is, can I deploy this app to my iOS device without enrolling in the Apple developer program? Since this is only for personal use and I do not wish to publish this app on any app store. Also, do I need to have a Mac with Xcode to do this?!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close your question, but please search, there are many resources about what you're asking. Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4952845/289501) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894969/develop-ios-app-using-phonegap-without-mac) for example.

Comment: Yes, you need a macbook with XCode and an Apple developer account.

Comment: @phi Hi! Thanks for the links. I did know about the free provisioning, but I think the app signed with a license that expires in 7 days (I could be wrong). And I have come across PhoneGap as well. I thought it was for native iOS app development. Are these still the solutions for PWAs as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For developing a Progressive Web App for iOS, you won't need Xcode and a Macbook since it is basically still a website with enhancements. However, bear in mind that PWA support on iOS is very limited. Android has much better PWA support.

[This article](https://medium.com/@firt/whats-new-on-ios-12-2-for-progressive-web-apps-75c348f8e945) gives an overview of what is currently possible